# Cascading DropDownList values dont show values asp.net mvc jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Tryin to create Car brand and model based cascading dropdownlist, but unfortunately the values dont show up in the model list. I get correct response when selecting car Brand for example Bmw returns JSON list of ["E30", "E46", "X5"], but in the SelectList the options wont show.

Here i return JSON format :

```
public JsonResult GetModels(int brandID)
    {

        String[] models;

        using (CarsEntities1 dc = new CarsEntities1())
        {
            models = dc.Models.Where(a => a.Brand_ID == brandID).Select(a=>a.Model_name).ToArray();
            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                return new JsonResult
                {
                    Data = models,
                    JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
                };
            }
        }

        return new JsonResult
        {
            Data = "Not valid request",
            JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
        };

    }
```

Heres the jQuery function for showing models

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#brand_Brand_ID").change(function () {
            // this will call when Brand Dropdown select change
            var brandID = parseInt($("#brand_Brand_ID").val());
            if (!isNaN(brandID)) {
                var ddModel = $("#Model_ID");
                ddModel.empty(); // this line is for clear all items from Model dropdown
                ddModel.append($("<option></option").val("").html("Select model"));
                $.ajax({
                    url: "@Url.Action("GetModels","ModelSpec")",
                    type: "GET",
                    data: { brandID: brandID },
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {  //here the data is always correct                          
                            $.each(data, function (i, val) {     
                                ddModel.append(
                                        $("<option></option>").val(val.Model_name).html(val.Model_name));           
                            });
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("Fail");

                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: use `val` instead of `val.Model_name`

Comment: `console.log(data)` and see what you are getting?

Comment: Thank you Parth Trivedi!!! Works now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be

```
$.ajax({
                    url: "@Url.Action("GetModels","ModelSpec")",
                    type: "GET",
                    data: { brandID: brandID },
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {  //here the data is always correct                          
                            $.each(data, function (i, val) {     
                                //use val as it returns array of string
                                ddModel.append(
                                        $("<option></option>").val(val).html(val));           
                            });
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("Fail");

                    }
                });
```